# Magnolia custom content type as property

Tags: java, content-management-system, yaml, magnolia

I defined two content types:

author-ct.yaml

```
datasource:
  workspace: books
  rootPath: /
  namespaces:
    lib: https://www.magnolia-travel.com/jcr/1.0/lib
  autoCreate: true

model:
  nodeType: lib:author
  properties:
    - name: name
    - birthdate: Date
```

books-ct.yaml

```
datasource:
  workspace: books
  rootPath: /
  namespaces:
    lib: https://www.magnolia-travel.com/jcr/1.0/lib
  autoCreate: true

model:
  nodeType: lib:book
  properties:
    - name: author
      type: lib:author
    - name: ed
      type: Boolean
    - name: title
    - name: description
    - name: publisher
    - name: publish_date
      type: Date
    - name: isbn13
```

As you can see I defined author property with type lib:author (defined in `author-ct.yaml`)

When I create new item of type `lib:book` below editor appears:
[image]

I can type anything in author field and save the object without errors. Looks like Magnolia ignored type I provided and used type String for property 'author'. I would like to have some dropdown with defined authors there. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states "[You can only reference submodels defined in the same content type](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Content+type+Model+definition#ContenttypeModeldefinition-anc-property-definition-propertiesPropertydefinitionproperties)". Have you tried defining `lib:author` inside `books-ct.yaml`?

Comment: 'author' is not a submodel of 'lib:book', it's pretty independent. I found a solution via editors configuration, just need a time to post it :)